# Make box plot in R?

Tags: r

I've got a data set that I first want to group them by site and then make box plots per each year with different colours? So the output graph should represent site name in x-axis (NR_B,NR_C....) and box plot per each year for each site with different colours. I tried with following code but it doesn't work.Can anyone help me?

```r
ggplot(AllEstuaryData, aes(x=Site, y=TP, color=Year)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

```html
Site Year TP
NR_B 2001 216
NR_B 2001 254
NR_B 2001 216
NR_B 2001 216
NR_B 2001 215
NR_B 2001 206
NR_B 2001 224
NR_B 2001 212
NR_B 2001 215
NR_B 2001 208
NR_B 2001 195
NR_B 2001 214
NR_B 2003 209
NR_B 2003 203
NR_B 2003 214
NR_B 2003 196
NR_B 2003 200
NR_B 2003 207
NR_B 2003 203
NR_B 2003 195
NR_B 2003 210
NR_B 2003 210
NR_B 2004 199
NR_B 2004 200
NR_B 2004 207
NR_B 2004 205
NR_B 2004 216
NR_B 2004 216
NR_B 2004 209
NR_B 2004 199
NR_B 2004 218
NR_B 2004 214
NR_B 2005 278
NR_B 2005 247
NR_B 2005 262
NR_B 2005 256
NR_B 2005 240
NR_B 2005 260
NR_B 2005 282
NR_B 2005 259
NR_B 2005 239
NR_B 2005 272
NR_B 2010 260
NR_B 2010 240
NR_B 2010 250
NR_B 2015 260
NR_B 2015 280
NR_B 2015 270
NR_B 2015 240
NR_B 2015 270
NR_B 2015 240
NR_B 2015 260
NR_B 2015 280
NR_B 2015 240
NR_B 2015 270
NR_B 2018 270
NR_B 2018 300
NR_B 2018 280
NR_C 2001 374
NR_C 2001 355
NR_C 2001 370
NR_C 2001 380
NR_C 2001 356
NR_C 2001 343
NR_C 2001 365
NR_C 2001 356
NR_C 2001 382
NR_C 2001 368
NR_C 2001 358
NR_C 2001 373
NR_C 2003 385
NR_C 2003 433
NR_C 2003 357
NR_C 2003 422
NR_C 2003 376
NR_C 2003 394
NR_C 2003 394
NR_C 2003 398
NR_C 2003 390
NR_C 2003 380
NR_C 2004 395
NR_C 2004 410
NR_C 2004 395
NR_C 2004 415
NR_C 2004 349
NR_C 2004 384
NR_C 2004 420
NR_C 2004 419
NR_C 2004 393
NR_C 2004 389
NR_C 2005 404
NR_C 2005 394
NR_C 2005 408
NR_C 2005 431
NR_C 2005 373
NR_C 2005 442
NR_C 2005 407
NR_C 2005 414
NR_C 2005 396
NR_C 2005 484
NR_C 2010 430
NR_C 2010 390
NR_C 2010 320
NR_C 2018 430
NR_C 2018 390
NR_C 2018 420
NR_D 2001 239
NR_D 2001 225
NR_D 2001 229
NR_D 2001 221
NR_D 2001 214
NR_D 2001 212
NR_D 2001 282
NR_D 2001 234
NR_D 2001 226
NR_D 2001 235
NR_D 2001 254
NR_D 2001 217
NR_D 2003 233
NR_D 2003 236
NR_D 2003 215
NR_D 2003 248
NR_D 2003 250
NR_D 2003 232
NR_D 2003 217
NR_D 2003 228
NR_D 2003 232
NR_D 2003 218
NR_D 2004 228
NR_D 2004 229
NR_D 2004 228
NR_D 2004 212
NR_D 2004 221
NR_D 2004 220
NR_D 2004 239
NR_D 2004 244
NR_D 2004 263
NR_D 2004 242
NR_D 2005 258
NR_D 2005 251
NR_D 2005 234
NR_D 2005 276
NR_D 2005 248
NR_D 2005 266
NR_D 2005 249
NR_D 2005 265
NR_D 2005 251
NR_D 2005 262
NR_D 2010 300
NR_D 2010 300
NR_D 2010 390
NR_D 2018 250
NR_D 2018 230
NR_D 2018 260
NR_E 2012 630
NR_E 2012 710
NR_E 2012 820
NR_E 2013 540
NR_E 2013 540
NR_E 2013 560
NR_E 2018 410
NR_E 2018 390
NR_E 2018 410
NR_E 2012 2100
NR_E 2012 1610
NR_E 2012 1800
NR_E 2013 1000
NR_E 2013 1000
NR_E 2013 1000
NR_E 2015 1490
NR_E 2015 1590
NR_E 2015 1490
NR_E 2015 1530
NR_E 2015 1320
NR_E 2015 1430
NR_E 2015 1670
NR_E 2015 1420
NR_E 2015 1400
NR_E 2015 1450
NR_E 2016 1560
NR_E 2016 1450
NR_E 2016 1500
NR_E 2018 2100
NR_E 2018 1760
NR_E 2018 1540
```

Comment: The data names in your code and the sample data look nothing alike. Can you fix one of them so that they are consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Desired output

> So the output graph should represent site name in x-axis (NR_B,NR_C....)
>   and box plot per each year for each site with different colours.

You need to pass the `fill/color` as `factor(Year)`. That will tell `ggplot` that is a discrete category.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Site, y=TP, fill=factor(Year))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Produces
[image]

This is outside the question, but, given the nature of the data you might want to consider a different type of visualization.

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Year), TP))+
 geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
 facet_wrap(~Site, scales="free_y")
```

[image]